# How to use MIME types for RDF typed literals

Tags: rdf, mime-types

RDF allows to use [typed literals](https://patterns.dataincubator.org/book/typed-literal.html) to specify the data type of string values. This is usually used for XML Schema datatypes such as `xsd:integer` and `xsd:date`, e.g.

```
<https://example.org/> dc:created "1999-12-17"^^xsd:date.
```

How can typed literals in RDF be used to specify data type defined by (or extending the) [IANA MIME Types registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)? I'd like to do something like this:

```
<https://example.org/>
  dc:description "I love cookies!" ;
  dc:description "I <em>love</em> cookies!"^^<text/html> ;
  dc:description "I *love* cookies!"^^<text/x-markdown> ;
  dc:description "I \\emph{love} cookies!"^^<application/x-tex> .
```

But plain MIME types are no valid datatype IRIs. Does an official URI namespace exist for MIME types and have such URIs been used for RDF typed literals?

Comment: There exists the `rdf:HTML` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to use MIME types as RDF (or XML Schema) datatypes, because it is ambiguous what such a thing would mean ‒ MIME types describe a sequence of *bytes*, while RDF literals are always a sequence of Unicode characters. You'd have to define a method the lexical value should be converted to the byte sequence and then interpreted, and for non-textual formats, you would likely have to start from `xsd:base64Binary` or `xsd:hexBinary`. In addition to that, some of your examples are only *fragments*, not documents valid on their own, so let's look at other options first:

##### Non-MIME datatypes

I'd recommend first looking for concrete identifiers for the formats you want to support, but even then you will likely have several options:

- `rdf:XMLLiteral`, `rdf:HTML`, and `rdf:JSON` are official and should be used for valid literals in these languages.
- [*Extra Types!*](http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/xtypes/) is an existing vocabulary for formats and fragments. For your example, you could easily use [`xtypes:Fragment-HTML`](http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/xtypes/#xtypes:Fragment-HTML), [`xtypes:Fragment-Markdown`](http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/xtypes/#xtypes:Fragment-Markdown), or [`xtypes:Fragment-LaTeX`](http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/xtypes/#xtypes:Fragment-LaTeX). What might be a bit ambiguous is what exactly a "fragment" means here. I assume it means that something like `'<tag attr="a">'^^xtypes:Fragment-XML` is valid, while `'<tag attr="a">'^^rdf:XMLLiteral` is not (it must be self-contained, akin to `application/xml-external-parsed-entity`).
- All formats are also present as entities in DBPedia, so you could use a URI like [`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Markdown`](https://dbpedia.org/page/Markdown), but these are not explicitly defined as datatypes, so some processors might have a hard time trying to find their definition.
- Another nice vocabulary is [*Unique URIs for File Formats*](https://www.w3.org/ns/formats/) from W3C, but it only contains RDF serialization formats and does not explicitly define them as datatypes either.
- Some data formats might have existing YAML tags, which are very similar to XML Schema datatypes and are representable using URIs. I was however unable to find more examples other than `tag:yaml.org,2002:yaml` for YAML.
- There is also a remote possibility to derive URIs from PUBLIC identifiers that were used for SGML notations. For TeX, the URI would be `urn:publicid:%2B:ISBN+0-201-13448-9;Knuth:NOTATION+The+TeXbook:EN`, but these are not produced anymore (you can find a collection of them [here](https://is4code.blogspot.com/2021/12/identifiers-for-some-file-formats.html)).

I would not recommend using any other URI scheme than `http(s)` however, since at least humans should be able to find out what it means through HTTP.

##### URIs for MIME types

If you want to have URIs for MIME types (but not necessarily used as datatypes), you could use something like [uri4uri](https://uri4uri.is4.site/mime.html/) to arrive at RDF descriptions of MIME types, for example [`https://w3id.org/uri4uri/mime/text/markdown`](https://uri4uri.is4.site/mime.html/text/markdown) (but note that the `charset` parameter is required for Markdown, so it should be [`https://w3id.org/uri4uri/mime/text/markdown;charset=utf-8`](https://uri4uri.is4.site/mime.html/text/markdown;charset=utf-8) ‒ parameters are supported too!).

You could also refer to the IANA registration document such as https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/markdown, but that's just a document and not all MIME types have those. This URL pattern could also be used for non-standard MIME types such as `https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/yaml` but these will not be resolvable unless officially registered.

##### Use language tags

Another option I could come use up with is to (ab)use language tags instead of datatypes for this purpose, such as `zxx-Latn-x-md` for Markdown or `zxx-Latn-x-tex` for TeX. This is absolutely not standardized (except for `zxx` usable for, among other things, programming source codes, and `Latn` for texts using the Latin alphabet), and I would not recommend using it for literals that should be parsed ‒ think of it as affecting the presentation of the text, such as picking a syntax highlighter.

##### Use `data:` URIs

The only standardized way to combine a text and MIME type is using the `data` URI scheme, but you won't get a literal:

```
<https://example.org/>
  dc:description <data:text/markdown;charset=utf-8,I%20*love*%20cookies!> .

<data:text/markdown;charset=utf-8,I%20*love*%20cookies!>
  a <https://w3id.org/uri4uri/mime/text/markdown;charset=utf-8> ;
  rdf:value "I *love* cookies!" .
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive list of options (including some obviously non-recommended hacks). It looks like several ways exist to map MIME types to URIs but none of them has been accepted or widely adopted. I tend to use IANA URLs such as https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/csv for `text/csv`.

Comment: @Jakob Frankly in the majority of situations where MIME types are used, people just write them as strings, so there was not much need to care about URIs. Personally I went with uri4uri in my projects because it's *semantic* (you'd get a rich description even from something like [`image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8`](https://uri4uri.is4.site/mime.html/image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8)). We just need to get more people to use it and it will be fine ;)